# How to override properties from application.yml when using external tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I deploy my app in external tomcat as a WAR file because there are multiple applications run on the same tomcat.

In my `application.yml` inside `resources` directory, I have (among other properties):

```
logging:
   file: MY_APP.log
```

I want to override this value when the app will run into external tomcat. I created application-myapp.yml into `CATALINA_BASE/conf/application-myapp.yml` with the following contents:

```
logging:
   file: ${catalina.base}/logs/MY_APP.log
```

And in my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml", "file:${catalina.base}/conf/application-myapp.yml"})
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

}
```

but the value is not overriden and MY_APP.log is created in /bin directory where I execute `startup.bat` which means the logging.file property is not overriden by `conf/application-myapp.yml`.

**NOTE that I need this for some other properties. Like JDBC url, etc. logging.file is just an example!**

What I want is to have a permanent `application-myapp.yml` into tomcat/conf directory with some properties configured to work in production. These values to override the ones (where property exists in both config files) from `resources/application.yml`.

I tried a lot of things. I tried also to have `.properties` file, but no luck. I also tried the following:

```
@PropertySources(
   @PropertySource("classpath:application.yml"),
   @PropertySource(value = "file:${catalina.base}/conf/application-myapp.yml", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
)
```

but still...no luck. I also tried different order in @PropertySource annotations.

How can I achieve this in `Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE` version?

For example, if I have:

`resources/application.yml:`

```
property1: value1
property2: value2
property3: value3
```

`CATALINA_BASE/conf/application-myapp.yml:`

```
property2: value4
```

Application will start:

```
property1: value1
property2: value4 #<-- here, overriden by application-myapp.yml
property3: value3
```

Comment: Try inverting the order of parameters in `@PropertySource`

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I already did try this. Again, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

To use the external config, try setting the SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION environment variable like below:

```
export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=${catalina.base}/conf/application-myapp.yml
```